# iOS / Flickr - Upload photos on another user album with ObjectiveFlickr

Tags: objective-c, ios, upload, photo, flickr

I'm trying to develop an iOS app that uploads users' photos on my album.
It's possible to create an app that uploads users' photos on a default album with my login?
Example:

My mum download the app and she doesn't have a Flickr account.
She takes a photo and the app upload the photo on MY album with MY username and password stored within the application.
On my flickr account and in my album I'll have all the photo that users choose to upload on my album!

It's possible?

Thx